# Import model from Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler into Sparx Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I have an Oralce SQL Developer Data Modeler file (*.dmd) and wish to do some diagramming to integrate in an existing Sparx EA model.

For context, I'm an overall solution designer who needs to reflect certain DB concepts in other diagrams, not part of the DB team which creates the model.

From the situation described in the [Sparx forums in 2014](http://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php?topic=25665.0), I would have to (without access to another Oracle DB instance containing a realization of the model):

1. Create a Database from the .dmd (or exported .ddl) ... Oracle Express being the likely target
2. Create an ODBC connection as local data source on Windows
3. Import from that ODBC source in Sparx

Presumably, refreshes would follow the same path.  I only intend to go in one direction with those updates.  That is, I do not plan to make model changes in Sparx for round-tripping back into the Oracle model.

Is that still the only viable path to use a model from Data Modeler to Sparx?

Comment: Not my expertise, but basically yes. You might want to look into an add-in called DBMode https://community.sparxsystems.com/news/430-2database-modeling-accelerator-dbmode-released

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to DBMode, Thomas.  They seem to generate a DDL from Sparx model, but don't claim anything about importing DB model from DDL (or other).  Interesting even if not a fit for the specific situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the only way to reverse engineer a database in EA is to use an ODBC connection to a live database.

There is no SQL interpreter, and based on the comments from Sparx employees, this will not be developed in the near future.